# Is server side model validation need if client side validatioen already done?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am validating input data in client side using jQuery validate plugin.
Is it necessary doing validation in server side(if client side is valid)?
Is there security risks if I only validate in client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no trust to what happens on the client. All the values that you receive can be sent directly or augmented by any tool that supports it like Postman, Fiddler, etc. And it does not really require too deep knowledge, so you should expect anyone to be able to do that.

That means that you should not only validate the data that you receive at least the same way you do on the client, but you should also ensure that the user executing the action has access to do that. E.g. if you receive a request to update some object with Id=6, you should always verify that user has access to perform the operation (e.g. that an object belongs to the user etc.). Without this it is extremely easy to "hack" your web site (Just execute the same request with modified Id=7)

That does not mean you should not validate on the client. But the reason for client validation is different. It is to provide a better user experience by instant feedback (no postbacks) rather than to trust anything that comes from the client.

Regarding the answer to your question: it depends. Very likely there is no security risk involved. E.g. if your validation checks that email is valid, it can be bypassed, but the only thing you risk is that you won't be able to send a mail e.g., etc. If you check that phone is not empty, then you risk that it will either be empty or fail to be inserted in the database.

In this case you might decide not to bother, since valid uses of your application would not allow that and it won't be a security risk users posting bad data. So as usual you should decide if it is worth the time to implement the server validation. Please do remember that this does not mean you can skip important things like I described above, i.e. validating that user has access, etc.

In any case it is beneficial to have same server-side validation as client-side, but if it's worth it, is another question.

Comment: Thank you Ilya for your comprehensive answer. It is very helpful. In security point of view, you are right. Joe Audette's mentioned case is also another problem that might be occur.  Than you guys.

Answer (score 2):

yes, server side validation is always needed because client side validation can be bypassed by disabling javascript

Comment: It is not as straightforward as you write here really, since it might be no security problem at all to not have a server-side validation (corresponding to client side validation of phone, email, etc.). I have written a more comprehensive answer below. So even though client validation can not be trusted bypassing it might not always be a security issue.

Comment: I would absolutely hate to do every single validation in code on both ends. There are some things you just don't need it for.

Comment: it is pretty easy to do both if you use a model with data annotations declaratively, that is how you easily wire up the client side validation and the same thing allows you to simply check ModelState.IsValid in the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Never trust user and ALWAYS valid by server side. For example request can be easly spoofed by sending not valid data (that can be attack vector)